# How to find the Controls in panel (which is added through literal)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Textbox1.text is user can enter html page name, so that its is appending to panel through literal.(loading html page to pannel).

```
string val = TextBox1.Text;
string location = Server.MapPath(".");
string path = location + "\\HTML\\" + val + ".html"; // HTML IS FOLDER NAME IN MY PROJECT
string readText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
Panel1.Controls.Clear();
Literal lit = new Literal();                
lit.Text = readText;
Panel1.Controls.Add(lit);
```

Actually in Html page few controls which are in format of input (`<input style="position: relative;" id="T0" onmouseup="mUp(this.id)" class="ui-draggable" onmousedown="mDown(this.id)" value="" type="text">`)
I have to find those id's and text to save in database.
how to find the controls in panel now?

Answer (score 1):

Give an ID to the control when you add it.

```
Literal lit = new Literal();                
lit.Text = readText;
lit.ID = "myLiteral";
Panel1.Controls.Add(lit);
```

Then you can get it back as follows:

```
Literal lit = (Literal)Panel1.FincControl("myLiteral");
```

Remember that dynamically added controls must be created added again on every `PostBack` that follows as long as you want to have access to them.

Comment: Actually i have added controls dynamically and saved in html page... now am getting back that html page to give users to entries, that entries i have to save in database

Comment: for example label will be saved as

Comment: <label id="formname1" title="Click Settings Tab to Change the FORM Name" onmousedown="JavaScript:return mDown(this.id)">new1</label>

Comment: And you want to search for the label?

Answer (score 0):

Give your Literal an ID and then you can access it via FindControl...

```
Literal myLiteral = Panel1.FindControl("litId") as Literal;
if (myLiteral != null)
{
    // ... do something
}
```

EDIT: (Missed the last part of your question)

You need to use ParseControl([string value]) on the HTML content which returns a control and then add that control (containing all child controls) to the Panel.  Then you can use FindControl to locate child controls.  For this method, the controls must be .NET controls (ie.

Comment: <div id="formname">
<label id="formname1" title="Click Settings Tab to Change the FORM Name" onmousedown="JavaScript:return mDown(this.id)">new1</label>
</div><div id="cntpnl"><br><input style="position: relative;" id="T0" onmouseup="mUp(this.id)" class="ui-draggable" title="Click Properties Tab to Change the Text" onmousedown="mDown(this.id)" value="" type="text">

Comment: If thats the case, then you can't access/manipulate them via C#.  In there very least you need a `runat="server"` attribute and if you are going to use that, you might as well use .NET controls.  Your best bet in manipulating `<input>` controls is Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not give id to the control, u can find them by Panel1.Controls[index], since it is the first control added u can access at Panel1.Controls[0]